# JSON schema validation of array objects for different values

Tags: json

So I am having an issue validating multiple items in an array. I have a condition and depending on the condition there will be a different set of values allowed for another field. Now with the below schema and sample below it validates correctly but only with the first item in the array if i put invalid data in second item i do not get an error. I am using a basic online validator and would want to understand if i am missing something in the schema logic or if  i need a better validator.

My sample schema is

{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"object1": {
"description": "This is the test object with an array for conditions.",
"properties": {
"desctription": {"type": "string"},
"arrayItems": {
"type": "array",
"items": [
{"$ref": "#/$defs/myItem"}
]
}
}
}
},
"$defs": {
"myItem": {
"type": "object",
"required": [
"typeCode",
"color"
]
},
"properties": {
"typeCode": {
"type": "string",
"enum": [
"A",
"B"
]
},
"color": {
"type": "string",
"enum": [
"Red",
"Blue",
"Green",
"Orange"
]
}
},
"allOf": [
{
"if": {
"typeCode": {"const": "A"}
},
"then": {
"color": {
"enum": [
"Red",
"Orange"
]
}
}
},
{
"if": {
"typeCode": {"const": "B"}
},
"then": {
"color": {
"enum": [
"Blue",
"Green"
]
}
}
}
]
}
}
so for sample data
{
"object1" : {
"description" : "this is to test array conditions if all are valid",
"arrayItems" : [
{
"typeCode" : "A",
"color" : "Red"
},
{
"typeCode" : "B",
"color" : "Blue"
}
]

}
}

will validate correctly but
{
"object1" : {
"description" : "this is to test array conditions if all are valid",
"arrayItems" : [
{
"typeCode" : "A",
"color" : "Red"
},
{
"typeCode" : "B",
"color" : "Red"
}
]

}
}
should throw an error but it is not.  If i reverse the items in the array it then throws an error.  What am i missing?